# PhalconPHP: My webtools page have'nt any css or js and all links do'nt work

Tags: command-line, phalcon, phalcon-webtools, phalcon-devtools

I Created a project by this command:

> phalcon create-project invo --enable-webtools

But when i open this page:

> localhost/phalcon/invo/webtools.php

[image: webtools without any css or js]

What is the problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the base uri in your config.php baseUri = "/phalcon/invo/"

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this type of error after creating a project with phalcon command line tool. So to resolve this issue try the following steps:

1. In app/config/config.php add an entry under **[application]** staticUri = /projectname/
2. Replace projectname with your project name.